# Meteor is loading two instances of jQuery and loading bootstrap twice

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have a Meteor app that uses a reusable meteor package that I an writing too. The local package uses npm jquery and npm bootstrap and so does the app.

But it looks like When I add the package to the app, Meteor loads two separate instances of jquery and also loads bootstrap twice.

Here is the package.js snippet for including npm dependencies for the meteor package.

```
Npm.depends({
  'jquery': '2.2.4',
  'jquery-ui': '1.12.1',
  'bootstrap': '3.3.7',
  'bootstrap-select': '1.12.2',
  'datatables.net': '1.10.15',
  'datatables.net-dt': '1.10.15',
  'sweetalert': '1.1.3',
  'toastr': '2.1.2',
  'eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker': '4.17.47'
});
```

I am using the bootstrap dropdown and when I click on the drop down, the open drop down code is run twice, once in the bootstrap code from the package and once from the app. As a result the toggleClass adds and then removes the 'open' from the dropdown container resulting in the dropdown never really opening.

How do I make sure that Meteor package and app use the same npm jquery and bootstrap instances.

I am using ES6 modules for everything.

Answer (score 0):

According to MDG we should only declare/include npm packages dependencies at app level and not at package level

https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-is-loading-two-instances-of-jquery-and-loading-bootstrap-twice/37138/4